# adobe indesign atomation using .net

Tags: epub, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

can you give me some idea on how automate a simple functuin to export indd into pub.Do i need to have indesign server? thanks!

how about quark to  epub conversion automation? Thanks!
regards,

jerome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use VBScript to control InDesign desktop, but the best way would be to control InDesign Server via the SOAP interface, sending it VBScript or JavaScript to execute.